# Open cart integration with Other systems

Tags: java, php, mysql, mongodb, opencart

I want to know whether we can integrate Opencart with other application built in Java / Mongo-DB.

To be precise, A  back end system is developed using Java/ Mysql and Mongo DB. All products will be managed from this application(backend) and orders which are placed have to be pushed to this application from opencart(Frontend).

Can you guys help me to know possibility of how a communication between 2 systems, Opencart(Frontend) and Java application(Backend) can be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some development experience and a plan of action this can be achieved. The steps are as follows:

1. Define what system you would like to connect to. For me this was a MSSQL Database.
2. Come up with a plan of how to connect the two items and what needs to be exchanged.
3. Once this plan has been setup, you can develop the integration to Opencart, this can be done by simply adding CSV files to exchange data ora direct connection between the databases. Remember to ensure you link the correct fields of your other system to the correct fields of Opencart.
4. If done by CSV there must be a way to upload the updated results to your other system.
5. For a java system I came across [this system](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=20043) a while ago, not sure if it will help

Good luck with the integration, I have done an integration between a visual studio program in .net and opencart. So far so good